# Google Finance Historical Data Multiple Attributes?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-finance

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2, "all",(TODAY()-($N$2)),TODAY(),"DAILY")
```

The above code returns OHLC data for specified days with the date column.

What I want are only high, low and close columns.

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2, ("high", "low", "close"),(TODAY()-($N$2)),TODAY(),"DAILY")
```

This code doesn't work.

And if use:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2, "high",(TODAY()-($N$2)),TODAY(),"DAILY")
```

it returns high but with an added column named date.

So if I do this for all 3 (high, low, close) individually in different columns, I will get 6 columns instead of 3 (3 date columns are unnecessary for me).

I need just the high, low and close without the date column or at the most just 1 date column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2, "all", TODAY()-($N$2), TODAY(), "DAILY"), 2, 4)
```

[image: 0]

```
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&A2, "all", TODAY()-($N$2), TODAY(), "DAILY"), 
 "select Col2,Col3,Col4", -1)
```

[image: 0]